# The gang's all here?

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

Many people have fond memories of us.  A little over two years ago, said memories resurfaced when one of us died.  It's a shame, because that means we'll have to deal with him again at some point, and having to look him in the face while doing so is *not* gonna be fun.

But this summer, your happy memories of us will *probably* be ruined.  In fact, people are already making fun of our successors on social media, and they haven't even had a chance to really prove themselves yet.  Their grand entrance to the public eye was...underwhelming, to say the least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you

> Ghostbusters

Many people have fond memories of us. A little over two years ago, said memories resurfaced when one of us died.

> Harold Ramis died 24 February 2014

It's a shame, because that means we'll have to deal with him again at some point, and having to look him in the face while doing so is not gonna be fun.

But this summer, your happy memories of us will probably be ruined.

> The new movie's coming out in July

In fact, people are already making fun of our successors on social media, and they haven't even had a chance to really prove themselves yet.

> The *trailer* has many thumbs down on YouTube

Their grand entrance to the public eye was...underwhelming, to say the least.

> The original announcement was... not memorable.

Comment: You forgot to mention that the reason they'll have to deal with him is because he's now a ghost!